# UITextFiled auto Scroll up when typing Japanese

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uinavigationbar, uitextfielddelegate

i create textfield support Japanese ,English
when i typing english it ok
but when i typing Japanese
 view is move up  and hide current textfeild behide navigation bar

before typing >>> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyiXB.png

after typing>>>  https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEoxA.png

here my code

```
titleLabel = [[UITextField alloc]
                  initWithFrame:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)-(self.view.frame.size.width/1.1)/2,
                                           self.view.frame.size.height/6,
                                           self.view.frame.size.width/1.1,
                                           self.view.frame.size.height/10)];
 titleLabel.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    titleLabel.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
    titleLabel.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    titleLabel.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    titleLabel.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    titleLabel.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this line on your viewDidLoad

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
```